# ¿Cómo pasar los minutos a segundos en un Report Viewer?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, reportviewer

Necesito pasar los minutos a horas y minutos. Mi pregunta es como puedo sacar las horas y minutos en el informe en vez de sacarlos en minutos. Aquí les dejo una imagen, de como salen los minutos en estos momentos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pudieran ayudar lo agradecería mucho.Gracias.

Esta es la expresión que pongo en el informe para mostrar los minutos totales

=Sum(CInt(Fields!suma_minutos.Value))

Comment: Puedes poner algo del código de como lo generas para poder ayudarte mejor?

Comment: No es la misma pregunta que hiciste ayer?

Comment: es parecida pero como es la suma de minutos totalizada, no me sirve lo de ayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el reportViewer, sobre la celda que muestra los minutos, das click derecho, seleccionas "Expresion" -> Funciones Comunes -> Fecha & Hora -> hora. 
Para tu código deberia quedar así. 
=Hour(Sum(CInt(Fields!suma_minutos.Value))) o =Hour(Sum(Fields!suma_minutos.Value))
Lo tengo funcionando en un proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @MattiasPeralta al final lo arreglé de otra forma.

Comment: Podrías responder a tu consulta de la manera en que lo solucionaste? Asi dar por cerrado el tema y ayudar al próximo que tenga la duda.

Answer (score 1):

Al final, en la expresión del Report Viewer puse esta expresion:

=Truncate((Sum(CInt(Fields!suma_minutos.Value)))/60)&""& "h :" &" "&((Sum(CInt(Fields!suma_minutos.Value))) Mod 60) &""& "min"